# iOS: Switch UIViews using ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, frp

I am having some trouble kicking-off with ReactiveCocoa

So basically - I have 2 (potentially N) `UIButtons` which when tapped on should trigger a different view to be displayed on the screen.

At the moment I am achieving it in the following way:

```
- (IBAction)firstButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    [self processViewDisplayForViewType:ViewTypeFirstType];

}

- (IBAction)secondButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    [self processViewDisplayForViewType:ViewTypeSecondType];

}

-(void)processViewDisplayForViewType:(ViewType)viewType{

    switch (viewType) {

        case ViewTypeFirstType:

            //process showing a view based on the given type

            break;

        case ViewTypeSecondType:

            //process showing a view based on the given type

            break;
        default:
            break;

    }

    self.currentViewType = viewType;

}
```

Now, if I have other display types I would need to add aditional statements in the switch block... so I hope I can solve this using ReactiveCocoa and FRP. Anybody can point me in the right direction on solving this ?

Comment: What's the problem with current code? In this particular case RC may offer you some syntax sugar in cost of perfomance.

Comment: I don't see much problem of this code. ReactiveCocoa won't know what your different views are, you still need such switch statement.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The way I was imagining this to turn out was to have a signal attached to `currentViewType` and have it fire when the its value changes... I do understand now that a switch of some sort must be used regardless of using RC or not.